# Why is login with facebook, using native app, works only on mobile data?

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I was searching whole day for an answer on this..
The idea is the following, if I don't use native Facebook app seems fine. 
But, otherwise it works ONLY using 3G, on wifi it keeps loading before I get the permissions dialog.

Comment: Do you any code or logs?

Comment: I get nothing on logcat, also I think it is not related to code.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But we have an option like if in the device the app is not installed then we give popup of Facebook login. So are you try that? And I have used it with 2G only.

Comment: As I said, without the native Facebook App login flow works okay. It redirects me to a web page where I login using Facebook account. but that's all...Anyway, After all I found out that it is because of the wifi from the place I work. It was working perfectly on other wifi networks :) So it might be an IPv6 problem. 
Thanks anyway guys